# Getting TypeError in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Following is my Angular 2 code:

```
    <ion-grid *ngFor="let item of menuData;  let i = index; " ng-init="getAllItemToGrid()">
    <img src="{{'assets/Products/'+menuData[i].image}}" ng-click="onLogin()" width="100%">
    <a class="item item-icon-right assertive" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: none;">
      <p ng-click="" style="font-size: 12px;text-align:left; padding-left: 10px">
        {{menuData[i].name}}<br/>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;color: black;">&#8364; {{i+1 < menuData.length}}</span>
      </p>
      <button ion-button (click)="addToCart(item)" type="submit" color="danger" icon-left block style="width:150px;  height: 25px;">
     <ion-icon ios="ios-cart" style="position: absolute;left:5%;"></ion-icon>
      <p> &emsp; ADD TO CART</p>
    </button>
    </a>
  </ion-col>
```

When I use the `menuData[i].image` the list will be populate image from array list one by one, but when I use `menuData[i+1].image` I'm getting error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Then use `menuData[i].image`... :/

Comment: Just so you know... Javascript and Java isn't the same thing. Look it up :)

Comment: i couldent use anguler 2 tage bcz it need 1500 reputation

Answer (score 1):

Try targeting `item.image` instead of `menuData[i].image` as you are already looping over `menuData` array items and don't need to target the index, you have the full `item` object available on each iteration.

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let item of menuData;  let i = index; " ng-init="getAllItemToGrid()">
    <img src="{{'assets/Products/'+ item.image}}" ng-click="onLogin()" width="100%">
...
```

The reason you are getting `undefined` error is because with `menuData[i+1].image` on the last iteration of the loop, effectively index `i` is out of bounds and targets an invalid item. Are you trying to display the image from the **next** `item` of the array on the current `item`?

I've created a simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vjyqGMFiakoiL7gMPqIS?p=preview) demonstrating the different approaches to targeting the `item` in the `*ngFor`. You can use the [safe navigation operator (?.)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) to only try accessing an object property if it exists, and display/outputting `null` otherwise. In the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vjyqGMFiakoiL7gMPqIS?p=preview), notice how the last iteration outputs `null` as the index `[i + 1]` does not have a correlating `item` in `menuData` to retrieve.

[*ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor) is simply iterating over each item in array `menuData` using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), in this case creating a *template input variable* called `item`. `menuData[i+1]` will always cause an error on the last iteration of `let item of menuData`. If the array has 3 items for example, trying to access index `3` (on last iteration of loop) will cause an error, there is no `item`/object at index `3`. The last numerical index of an array of 3 items would be `2`. In Java this would be `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, in C# this would be `IndexOutOfRangeException`, etc. You simply cannot access properties of an item that doesn't exist, that is why the error is occurring. The [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vjyqGMFiakoiL7gMPqIS?p=preview) shows the current index and next index, everything is technically fine until the last iteration of the `*ngFor`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: there is a gird view in my application the first column should be first element and 2nd column should be second element that's why i use [i+1]

Comment: `let i = index;` starts at index `0` so you shouldn't need to do `[i+1]`. Index `0` would target the first item, `1` would target the next, and so on. This would be similar to Java, C#, Python, etc. Try just target either `item.image` or if you must, menuData[i].image and see if that works.

Comment: item.image ,  menuData[i].image and  menuData[#].image(#= numbers) all are perfectly working but  menuData[i+1].image is not working

Comment: menuData[i+1] will always cause an error on the last iteration of `let item of menuData`. If the array has 3 items for example, trying to access index `3` will cause an error, there is no item in index `3`. The last numerical index of an array of 3 items if `2`. In Java this would be `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, in C# this would be `IndexOutOfRangeException`, etc. You simply cannot access properties of an item that doesn't exist, that is why the error is occurring.

Comment: i got it bro awesome explanation thanks any suggestion plz